# MySQL UPDATE Query wont work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

What is wrong with this script? I cannot figure out the issue!

```
function editAccount() {
  $id = $_POST['id'];   
  $rep = $_POST['rep'];
  $lastchange = date('mdY');
  $account = $_POST['account'];
  $areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
  $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $state = $_POST['state'];
  $zip = $_POST['zip'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $fax = $_POST['fax'];
  $descmaker1 = $_POST['descmaker1'];
  $descmaker2 = $_POST['descmaker2'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $cvendor = $_POST['cvendor'];
  $cequipment = $_POST['cequipment'];
  $leaseexp1 = $_POST['leaseexp1'];
  $leaseexp2 = $_POST['leaseexp2'];
  $leaseexp3 = $_POST['leaseexp3'];
  $leaseexp4 = $_POST['leaseexp4'];
  $leaseexp5 = $_POST['leaseexp5'];
  $leaseexp6 = $_POST['leaseexp6'];
  $volume = $_POST['volume'];
  $notes = $_POST['notes'];     

  mysql_db_query("UPDATE accounts 
                     SET (lastchange = '$lastchange',
                             account = '$account',
                            areacode = '$areacode',
                              number = '$number',
                            address1 = '$address1',
                            address2 = '$address2',
                                city = '$city',
                               state = '$state',
                                 zip = '$zip',
                                 fax = '$fax',
                          descmaker1 = '$descmaker1',
                          descmaker2 = '$descmaker2',
                               title = '$title',
                               email = '$email',
                             cvendor = '$cvendor',
                          cequipment = '$cequipment',
                           leaseexp1 = '$leaseexp1',
                           leaseexp2 = '$leaseexp2',
                           leaseexp3 = '$leaseexp3',
                           leaseexp4 = '$leaseexp4',
                           leaseexp5 = '$leaseexp5',
                           leaseexp6 = '$leaseexp6',
                              volume = '$volume',
                               notes = '$notes')            
         WHERE id = $id");
}
```

Error:

Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_db_query() in /home/content/53/7311353/html/cca/accounts/include/processAct.php on line 83

Line is: `WHERE id=$id");`

Comment: @JD Audi - What is line 83 in your snippet ?

Comment: I hope you realize what a giant security hole this function is

Comment: @Sam Dufel , It probably is.. But Its so nested inside of a bunch of session checks and permission checks I don't see a problem for now.. its just for a small time shop doing simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, is you're calling the wrong function.  [`mysql_db_query`](http://php.net/mysql_db_query) should be [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query).

You also don't need the parenthesis after `SET`.

Regarding sql injection, I suggest you escape all `$_POST` variables with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Answer (score 2):

In the `UPDATE` command, lose the parenthesis. That's it.

Also, please, beware of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

**Update**

Here's how the final code should look like:

```
function editAccount() {
  $id = $_POST['id'];   
  $rep = $_POST['rep'];
  $lastchange = date('mdY');
  $account = $_POST['account'];
  $areacode = $_POST['areacode'];
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
  $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $state = $_POST['state'];
  $zip = $_POST['zip'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $fax = $_POST['fax'];
  $descmaker1 = $_POST['descmaker1'];
  $descmaker2 = $_POST['descmaker2'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $cvendor = $_POST['cvendor'];
  $cequipment = $_POST['cequipment'];
  $leaseexp1 = $_POST['leaseexp1'];
  $leaseexp2 = $_POST['leaseexp2'];
  $leaseexp3 = $_POST['leaseexp3'];
  $leaseexp4 = $_POST['leaseexp4'];
  $leaseexp5 = $_POST['leaseexp5'];
  $leaseexp6 = $_POST['leaseexp6'];
  $volume = $_POST['volume'];
  $notes = $_POST['notes'];     

  mysql_query("UPDATE accounts 
                     SET  lastchange = '$lastchange',
                             account = '$account',
                            areacode = '$areacode',
                              number = '$number',
                            address1 = '$address1',
                            address2 = '$address2',
                                city = '$city',
                               state = '$state',
                                 zip = '$zip',
                                 fax = '$fax',
                          descmaker1 = '$descmaker1',
                          descmaker2 = '$descmaker2',
                               title = '$title',
                               email = '$email',
                             cvendor = '$cvendor',
                          cequipment = '$cequipment',
                           leaseexp1 = '$leaseexp1',
                           leaseexp2 = '$leaseexp2',
                           leaseexp3 = '$leaseexp3',
                           leaseexp4 = '$leaseexp4',
                           leaseexp5 = '$leaseexp5',
                           leaseexp6 = '$leaseexp6',
                              volume = '$volume',
                               notes = '$notes'         
         WHERE id = $id");
}
```

Comment: @Adrian which parenthesis? I tried removing some and it just gave me more errors.

Comment: @JD: The parenthesis after `SET`.

Comment: Yes, inside the update command. The one right after `SET` and the the one right after `$notes`

Comment: @Adrian Nope. Still same error. Wrong parameter count on WHERE id=$id"); (line 83)

Comment: Also, @JD, take your time to read about SQL Injection. The way your command is being processed, you can get your DB screwed easily by external attacks.

Comment: @Adrian, I know this. Im not too worried about that right now I just want to get it working.

Comment: `mysql_db_query` should be `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 1):

[According to PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php), the deprecated function `mysql_db_query()` takes at least two parameters.  First, is the database name and second is the SQL query.  You've only specified the SQL query.

```
resource mysql_db_query ( string $database , string $query [, resource $link_identifier ] )
```

So in your case:

```
mysql_db_query('yourdatabasename', "UPDATE accounts set....");
```

More common these days is to use `mysql_query()`, which will make use of the database previously selected with `mysql_select_db()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether mysql connection is established.
Some times that might also be a problem

```
mysql_query("UPDATE accounts 
                     SET (lastchange = '$lastchange',
                             account = '$account',
                            areacode = '$areacode',
                              number = '$number',
                            address1 = '$address1',
                            address2 = '$address2',
                                city = '$city',
                               state = '$state',
                                 zip = '$zip',
                                 fax = '$fax',
                          descmaker1 = '$descmaker1',
                          descmaker2 = '$descmaker2',
                               title = '$title',
                               email = '$email',
                             cvendor = '$cvendor',
                          cequipment = '$cequipment',
                           leaseexp1 = '$leaseexp1',
                           leaseexp2 = '$leaseexp2',
                           leaseexp3 = '$leaseexp3',
                           leaseexp4 = '$leaseexp4',
                           leaseexp5 = '$leaseexp5',
                           leaseexp6 = '$leaseexp6',
                              volume = '$volume',
                               notes = '$notes')            
         WHERE id = $id")
```

this is the syntax to update the query, use mysql_query instead of mysql_db_query